# How to export mongodb db collections to another js file?

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, mongodb, database-connection

I have initialized the connection to my mongodb and now export the db to other nodejs files. How can I do that?

i thought of something like this but it is giving errors.

```
let database;
export const connectDB = async () => {
  const client = new MongoClient(config.dbUri, {
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
  });

  try {
    await client.connect();
    database = client.db('azkaben');
    logger.info('Connected to Database');
  } catch (e) {
    logger.error(e);
  } finally {
    await client.close();
  }
};

export default database
```

Error : undefined value of database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`database` will always be null when you import it.

`connectDB` is aync call by the time it executes your database variable is already loaded as null.

`connectDB` you can return `database` from here.

```
export const connectDB = async () => {
  const client = new MongoClient(config.dbUri, {
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
  });

  try {
    await client.connect();
    database = client.db('azkaben');
    return database; // you can get from here
    logger.info('Connected to Database');
  } catch (e) {
    logger.error(e);
  } finally {
    await client.close();
  }
};
```

---

Updated code

```
export const connectDB = async () => {
  if (database) return database; // return if database already connected. 
  const client = new MongoClient(config.dbUri, {
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
  });

  try {
    await client.connect();
    database = client.db('azkaben');
    return database; // you can get from here
    logger.info('Connected to Database');
  } catch (e) {
    logger.error(e);
  } finally {
    await client.close();
  }
};
```

Comment: But, if i will do that , I have to connect to database every time I import that db

Comment: @anitashrivastava In that case you can use `const getDatabse = async() => databse;` function to get the value, but you need to make sure the application is connected to database 1st after that your code execution starts.  `getDatabse().then(db =>  query)`.

Comment: @anitashrivastava or you can even use `const getDatabse => databse;` but sure your database is connected before you call `getDatabse`.

Comment: @anitashrivastava updated answer with 1 more option.